# Ubuntu SDK IDE quits with Segmentation fault when running example code

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I installed Ubuntu SDK from `ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa` on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit. Then I created device kit ubuntu-sdk-15.04 armhf.
When I try to run with `CTRL + R` example below from: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/qml/tutorials/building-your-first-qml-app/ Ubuntu SDK IDE stops with segmentation fault.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1

/*!
    \brief MainView with a Label and Button elements.
*/

MainView {
    id: root
    // objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
    objectName: "mainView"

    // Note! applicationName needs to match the "name" field of the click manifest
    applicationName: "currencyconverter.yourname"

    /*
     This property enables the application to change orientation
     when the device is rotated. The default is false.
    */
    //automaticOrientation: true

    // Removes the old toolbar and enables new features of the new header.
    useDeprecatedToolbar: false

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    property real margins: units.gu(2)
    property real buttonWidth: units.gu(9)

    Page {
        title: i18n.tr("Currency Converter")

    }
}
```

I thought that ubuntu-sdk package from PPA have everything needed but it turns out its not
In my opinion i need additional packages not mentioned in tutorial installed to be able to start developing for Ubuntu. What are those additional packages?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is installing `ubuntu-sdk-dev` package from `ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk-dev
```

Currently there is a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-ide/+bug/1510061 ubuntu-sdk-ide package it's missing some dependencies.